# I need help Identifying these two varistors

Tags: identification, varistor

I need assistance in ordering replacement varistors for the light dimmer switch in my 1998 Nissan Frontier. These are from 2 different switches which have exact part numbers, but the varistors are different.  I am attempting to repair these switches, and want to replace both of these varistors.  If anyone could help me in getting replacement part numbers for these and get them ordered I would greatly appreciate the help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Epcos (now TDK), Matsushita (Panasonic). Then browse by product families; they're probably still in production, even.

Neither seems damaged, I don't see reason to replace them.